# Application Insights pageView.duration compounds

Tags: web, azure-application-insights, aurelia

I have a SPA application developed in Aurelia. When I query a session (see query below) I see outrageous duration measurements. The page duration for consecutive pages continues to increase. The time stamp indicates that the pageViews are happening in much less time than the duration indicates. Other sessions work as expected with duration in range when compared to the time stamp.

We are using the following NPM Package in Aurelia for logging to Application Insights: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-application-insights

How can I get the duration to be more accurate?

Example Query

```
pageViews
| where timestamp >= ago(1h) and session_Id == "FPVOw" 
| order by timestamp asc
```

Example Duration Times

```
timestamp [UTC]         name        duration    performanceBucket
2017-12-28T02:51:46.188 Application 2,934,817   >=5min
2017-12-28T02:51:57.289 Application 2,946,021   >=5min
2017-12-28T02:52:17.852 Application 2,966,581   >=5min
2017-12-28T02:52:21.935 Application 2,970,662   >=5min
2017-12-28T02:52:26.540 Application 2,975,271   >=5min
2017-12-28T02:52:53.082 Application 3,001,815   >=5min
2017-12-28T02:52:58.192 Application 3,006,912   >=5min
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-application-insights
That is the Application Insights package being used for Aurelia here.  

We are attempting to figure out how we can reduce these types of outliers from coming through.  We're unsure if this was a bug or what could have caused data like this to come through.